# makefile:28: recipe for target 'usage.msg' failed make: *** [usage.msg] Error 126

Tags: makefile

I was trying to execute make and received the below error:

```
echo '/* GENERATED CODE, DO NOT EDIT */' > usage.msg.tmp
/home/kiran/bin/x86_64/stringify usage.txt >> usage.msg.tmp
/bin/sh: 1: /home/kiran/bin/x86_64/stringify: Permission denied
makefile:28: recipe for target 'usage.msg' failed
make: *** [usage.msg] Error 126
```

The makefile has the following code:

```
#create msg from text
%.msg: %.txt
echo '/* GENERATED CODE, DO NOT EDIT */' > $@.tmp
${STRINGIFY} $< >> $@.tm
mv -f $@.tmp $@
```

I tried changing permission for the files but nothing helped. I think that makefile is trying to execute  ${STRINGIFY} as a directory. Please let me know if my understanding is right. Is there something i need to do about it?

Answer (score 0):

For me it seems that `make` wants to execute the program `stringifiy` which is found in the directory `/home/kiran/bin/x86_64/`. It seems that this program really exists, but the execute permissions are not set.

You can check the permissions with

```
ls -l /home/kiran/bin/x86_64/stringify
```

There should be an output like

> -rw-r--r-- 1 kiran kiran 16 Sep 16 20:30 /home/kiran/bin/x86_64/stringify

**I have no idea what this stringify program is going to do, so do the following on your own risk.**

You can try to set execute permissions with

```
chmod u+x /home/kiran/bin/x86_64/stringify
```

After that, the output of the `ls` command from above should be:

> -rwxr--r-- 1 kiran kiran 16 Sep 16 20:30 /home/kiran/bin/x86_64/stringify

Note the letter x close to the beginning.

You should search some information about file access permissions and how to change them.